# Xpages using @jdbcupdate cant set timestamp field to null

Tags: db2, relational-database, xpages, lotus-domino

I am using for a project   @jdbcupdate from extension library ,  but I cant set to null a TIMESTAMP field.

Example: I have a record in a table with a timestamp field set to 16/04/2018 15:52:18 and want set to null

@JdbcUpdate(conndb,db2tablename,saveobject,fieldcondizione,id)

saveobject is an HashMap where I try to force to null

saveobject.put(Key,"0000-00-00 00:00:00" )

but in the timestamp field  it write  30/11/0002 00:00:00 instead of null.

There is a way to set to null a timestamp field or Date field with the relational control of Extension library for DB2 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked in the database catalog if the column has a DEFAULT value specified , or whether the table has triggers that set that column?  Note that setting a timestamp to all zeroes is different to setting null.

Comment: Hi thanks for replay,  I checked in db catalog and have not Default value specified and neither trigger that set that column.I need to set to null that timestamp field without modify the db2 table. there is a way with @JdbcUpdate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashmap supports null values and null keys according to its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).
i.e. you can put null into the HashMap entry( saveobject.put(Key, null); )

But if the target column has 'not null with default' then Db2 will use the default.